# I get null or none when trying to get values from decoded Json with stripe using php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

hello I am implementing stripe into my application and intend to make use of Webhooks to update user subscriptions with time as payment is made.

I setup my Webhook url and I have done my test.

everything works the response is successful and the Json result is sent back.

I try to echo one of the fields returned back "customer_email"

but it returns null or None

but I can see the customer email wen the result is return in the console of my stripe account.

please have in mind I'm testing as demo account,

below is my code

```
require_once('str/init.php');
// Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON:
$input = @file_get_contents('php://input');

$obj = json_decode($input);
// Access values from the returned object




echo $obj->customer_email;
```

when I try to do a dump I get this.

```
string(3753) "{
  "created": 1326853478,
  "livemode": false,
  "id": "evt_00000000000000",
  "type": "customer.subscription.updated",
  "object": "event",
  "request": null,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "api_version": "2018-11-08",
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "sub_00000000000000",
      "object": "subscription",
      "application_fee_percent": null,
      "billing": "charge_automatically",
      "billing_cycle_anchor": 1560229531,
      "billing_thresholds": null,
      "cancel_at": null,
      "cancel_at_period_end": false,
      "canceled_at": null,
      "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
      "created": 1560229531,
      "current_period_end": 1562821531,
      "current_period_start": 1560229531,
      "customer": "cus_00000000000000",
      "days_until_due": null,
      "default_payment_method": null,
      "default_source": null,
      "default_tax_rates": [

      ],
      "discount": null,
      "ended_at": null,
      "items": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "si_00000000000000",
            "object": "subscription_item",
            "billing_thresholds": null,
            "created": 1560229532,
            "metadata": {
            },
            "plan": {
              "id": "gold_00000000000000",
              "object": "plan",
              "active": true,
              "aggregate_usage": null,
              "amount": 2000,
              "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
              "created": 1394752996,
              "currency": "eur",
              "interval": "month",
              "interval_count": 1,
              "livemode": false,
              "metadata": {
              },
              "nickname": null,
              "product": "prod_00000000000000",
              "tiers": null,
              "tiers_mode": null,
              "transform_usage": null,
              "trial_period_days": null,
              "usage_type": "licensed"
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "subscription": "sub_00000000000000"
          }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 1,
        "url": "/v1/subscription_items?subscription=sub_FEVBuUqKY6CieO"
      },
      "latest_invoice": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "plan": {
        "id": "gold_00000000000000",
        "object": "plan",
        "active": true,
        "aggregate_usage": null,
        "amount": 2000,
        "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
        "created": 1394752996,
        "currency": "eur",
        "interval": "month",
        "interval_count": 1,
        "livemode": false,
        "metadata": {
        },
        "nickname": null,
        "product": "prod_00000000000000",
        "tiers": null,
        "tiers_mode": null,
        "transform_usage": null,
        "trial_period_days": null,
        "usage_type": "licensed"
      },
      "quantity": 1,
      "schedule": null,
      "start": 1560229531,
      "start_date": 1560229531,
      "status": "active",
      "tax_percent": null,
      "trial_end": null,
      "trial_start": null
    },
    "previous_attributes": {
      "plan": {
        "id": "OLD_00000000000000",
        "object": "plan",
        "active": true,
        "aggregate_usage": null,
        "amount": 2000,
        "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
        "created": 1560229531,
        "currency": "eur",
        "interval": "month",
        "interval_count": 1,
        "livemode": false,
        "metadata": {
        },
        "nickname": null,
        "product": "prod_00000000000000",
        "tiers": null,
        "tiers_mode": null,
        "transform_usage": null,
        "trial_period_days": null,
        "usage_type": "licensed",
        "name": "Old plan"
      }
    }
  }
}"
```

all I want to achieve is to be able to echo out the "customer email"

please how do I do these

Comment: So what do you get when you add in a var_dump($input); and a var_dump($obj); so you can actually see what is going on. Edit your question and add in the results for these two.

Comment: I assume your $obj is an object of arrays, so you might need to loop over them to print out the customer email. Also what TimBrownlaw said

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly please could you be kind enough to gv me a guide on how to do this.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw the customer email does not get returned for sm reason again, but then I tried printing out interval which is returned in result that too returns "none"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok lets go through this...

So from your json string you get this.
I have assigned this to be `$json_string`

```
<?php
$json_string = '{
  "created": 1326853478,
  "livemode": false,
  "id": "evt_00000000000000",
  "type": "customer.subscription.updated",
  "object": "event",
  "request": null,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "api_version": "2018-11-08",
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "sub_00000000000000",
      "object": "subscription",
      "application_fee_percent": null,
      "billing": "charge_automatically",
      "billing_cycle_anchor": 1560229531,
      "billing_thresholds": null,
      "cancel_at": null,
      "cancel_at_period_end": false,
      "canceled_at": null,
      "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
      "created": 1560229531,
      "current_period_end": 1562821531,
      "current_period_start": 1560229531,
      "customer": "cus_00000000000000",
      "days_until_due": null,
      "default_payment_method": null,
      "default_source": null,
      "default_tax_rates": [

      ],
      "discount": null,
      "ended_at": null,
      "items": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "si_00000000000000",
            "object": "subscription_item",
            "billing_thresholds": null,
            "created": 1560229532,
            "metadata": {
            },
            "plan": {
              "id": "gold_00000000000000",
              "object": "plan",
              "active": true,
              "aggregate_usage": null,
              "amount": 2000,
              "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
              "created": 1394752996,
              "currency": "eur",
              "interval": "month",
              "interval_count": 1,
              "livemode": false,
              "metadata": {
              },
              "nickname": null,
              "product": "prod_00000000000000",
              "tiers": null,
              "tiers_mode": null,
              "transform_usage": null,
              "trial_period_days": null,
              "usage_type": "licensed"
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "subscription": "sub_00000000000000"
          }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 1,
        "url": "/v1/subscription_items?subscription=sub_FEVBuUqKY6CieO"
      },
      "latest_invoice": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "plan": {
        "id": "gold_00000000000000",
        "object": "plan",
        "active": true,
        "aggregate_usage": null,
        "amount": 2000,
        "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
        "created": 1394752996,
        "currency": "eur",
        "interval": "month",
        "interval_count": 1,
        "livemode": false,
        "metadata": {
        },
        "nickname": null,
        "product": "prod_00000000000000",
        "tiers": null,
        "tiers_mode": null,
        "transform_usage": null,
        "trial_period_days": null,
        "usage_type": "licensed"
      },
      "quantity": 1,
      "schedule": null,
      "start": 1560229531,
      "start_date": 1560229531,
      "status": "active",
      "tax_percent": null,
      "trial_end": null,
      "trial_start": null
    },
    "previous_attributes": {
      "plan": {
        "id": "OLD_00000000000000",
        "object": "plan",
        "active": true,
        "aggregate_usage": null,
        "amount": 2000,
        "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
        "created": 1560229531,
        "currency": "eur",
        "interval": "month",
        "interval_count": 1,
        "livemode": false,
        "metadata": {
        },
        "nickname": null,
        "product": "prod_00000000000000",
        "tiers": null,
        "tiers_mode": null,
        "transform_usage": null,
        "trial_period_days": null,
        "usage_type": "licensed",
        "name": "Old plan"
      }
    }
  }
}';
```

The trick here is to walk though the object. Think of these as rooms to a house which has rooms, which has cupboards which has draws and compartments in the drawers etc.

> You should try this code with the $json_string defined above included
>   in the same file. Note the use of var_dump so you can see what comes
>   out at each stage...

So you can access fields like so

```
$json_object = json_decode($json_string);
var_dump($json_object);

echo $json_object->object; // the object field is = 'event'
var_dump($json_object->data->object->plan->interval); // The interval field is = 'month'
```

Walking down the object ( which we can see from the var_dump of the json string, which is why we do that to see whats in it and where... We can get the "object" field and the "interval" field.

If we change this from an object of objects to an array of arrays by setting true in the json_decode, like

```
$json_object = json_decode($json_string,true); // set 2nd param to true, output an array of arrays - look it up
var_dump($json_object);

echo $json_object['object']; // 'event'
var_dump($json_object['data']['object']['plan']['interval']); // 'month'
```

You can see its now an associative array and the "path" to interval remains the same.

**UPDATE: This is the actual output when its run. Added for completeness.**

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'created' => int 1326853478
  public 'livemode' => boolean false
  public 'id' => string 'evt_00000000000000' (length=18)
  public 'type' => string 'customer.subscription.updated' (length=29)
  public 'object' => string 'event' (length=5)
  public 'request' => null
  public 'pending_webhooks' => int 1
  public 'api_version' => string '2018-11-08' (length=10)
  public 'data' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'object' => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'id' => string 'sub_00000000000000' (length=18)
          public 'object' => string 'subscription' (length=12)
          public 'application_fee_percent' => null
          public 'billing' => string 'charge_automatically' (length=20)
          public 'billing_cycle_anchor' => int 1560229531
          public 'billing_thresholds' => null
          public 'cancel_at' => null
          public 'cancel_at_period_end' => boolean false
          public 'canceled_at' => null
          public 'collection_method' => string 'charge_automatically' (length=20)
          public 'created' => int 1560229531
          public 'current_period_end' => int 1562821531
          public 'current_period_start' => int 1560229531
          public 'customer' => string 'cus_00000000000000' (length=18)
          public 'days_until_due' => null
          public 'default_payment_method' => null
          public 'default_source' => null
          public 'default_tax_rates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'discount' => null
          public 'ended_at' => null
          public 'items' => 
            object(stdClass)[4]
              ...
          public 'latest_invoice' => null
          public 'livemode' => boolean false
          public 'metadata' => 
            object(stdClass)[9]
              ...
          public 'plan' => 
            object(stdClass)[10]
              ...
          public 'quantity' => int 1
          public 'schedule' => null
          public 'start' => int 1560229531
          public 'start_date' => int 1560229531
          public 'status' => string 'active' (length=6)
          public 'tax_percent' => null
          public 'trial_end' => null
          public 'trial_start' => null
      public 'previous_attributes' => 
        object(stdClass)[12]
          public 'plan' => 
            object(stdClass)[13]
              ...
event
string 'month' (length=5)

array (size=9)
  'created' => int 1326853478
  'livemode' => boolean false
  'id' => string 'evt_00000000000000' (length=18)
  'type' => string 'customer.subscription.updated' (length=29)
  'object' => string 'event' (length=5)
  'request' => null
  'pending_webhooks' => int 1
  'api_version' => string '2018-11-08' (length=10)
  'data' => 
    array (size=2)
      'object' => 
        array (size=33)
          'id' => string 'sub_00000000000000' (length=18)
          'object' => string 'subscription' (length=12)
          'application_fee_percent' => null
          'billing' => string 'charge_automatically' (length=20)
          'billing_cycle_anchor' => int 1560229531
          'billing_thresholds' => null
          'cancel_at' => null
          'cancel_at_period_end' => boolean false
          'canceled_at' => null
          'collection_method' => string 'charge_automatically' (length=20)
          'created' => int 1560229531
          'current_period_end' => int 1562821531
          'current_period_start' => int 1560229531
          'customer' => string 'cus_00000000000000' (length=18)
          'days_until_due' => null
          'default_payment_method' => null
          'default_source' => null
          'default_tax_rates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'discount' => null
          'ended_at' => null
          'items' => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          'latest_invoice' => null
          'livemode' => boolean false
          'metadata' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'plan' => 
            array (size=19)
              ...
          'quantity' => int 1
          'schedule' => null
          'start' => int 1560229531
          'start_date' => int 1560229531
          'status' => string 'active' (length=6)
          'tax_percent' => null
          'trial_end' => null
          'trial_start' => null
      'previous_attributes' => 
        array (size=1)
          'plan' => 
            array (size=20)
              ...

event
string 'month' (length=5)
```

I hope that sheds some light on how to get the values you are after.

Have a play with it.

**NOTE:** 
As you can see, var_dump can get truncated which isn't always useful. To see everything you are better off using print_r. Something like...

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($json_object);
echo '</pre>';
```

Which makes things a little easier to read.

Comment: The Big eye opener is actually seeing the var_dump from the json_decode. That clearly shows the "Structure". I didn't include that in the answer as you can generate that yourself when you run the code.

Comment: thank u so much, It worked and most importantly I got the concept you were explaining to me

Comment: You are welcome. I have added a note to the answer at the end regarding var_dump and print_r.

Comment: @TeeFamakin What is even more important is knowing how you can debug this stuff so you can see whats going on :)

Comment: I honestly didn't want to come asking you how I could get the actual content in readable format, thanks a lot, so with what you gave me I just did this "print_r($json_object['data']['object']['plan']['interval']);"  thanks so much now I can do a lot with this